# What is the bottom left object in this picture of fantasy items?

Tags: object-identification

Recently I found it this picture on facebook.

[image]

My friends and I have tried to figure out what is the object (or weapon) that appears in the bottom left corner of the picture under Gandalf's staff. **What is that object?**

Comment: I don't know what the object opposite the screwdriver is

Comment: @NKCampbell A wand, likely a reference to Harry Potter.

Comment: It's your father's lightsaber. He wanted you to have it when you were old enough, but your uncle wouldn't allow it.

Comment: This would have been much cooler if the sword were Stormbringer.

Comment: "Gandalf's crosier"?  What is that?  wikipedia says: 
Eastern-style crosier of the Indian Orthodox (Malankara Orthodox Church) with serpents representing the staff of Moses
A crosier (also known as a crozier, paterissa, pastoral staff, or bishop's staff)[1] is a stylized staff carried by high-ranking Roman Catholic, Eastern Catholic, Eastern Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox, Anglican, and some Lutheran, United Methodist and Pentecostal prelates.   But the thing in the picture doesn't have a crosier shaped head, and Gandalf carried a staff, not a crosier.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Could be a difference in terminology caused by translation - it is likely that the asker is more familiar with the Spanish translation(s) than the English ones, which could've translated "staff" as "crosier".

Comment: The wand is the deathstick I believe.... the 'ultimate' wand in harry potter, one of the horcruxes(I think, someone will correct me if not), and amusing in many other ways.

Comment: @djsmiley2k - The elder wand is a long thin wand with three balls equally spaced along the stem. Nothing like the picture. It was also not a horcrux

Comment: @Valorum Nod, thank you - I went searching for it but forgot to come back and fix/acknowledge my error!.

Comment: @djsmiley2k You might be amused to discover that the wand is the only object in the design from real life.  It's actually the [Kymera Wand](http://www.thewandcompany.com/kymera-wand/), which is a remote control gadget you can buy to turn stuff on and off while pretending to be a wizard.

Comment: @J... - It certainly looks like it, but have you got any evidence?

Comment: @Valorum What more evidence do you need?  No other object I'm aware of has that exact silhouette.

Comment: @J... - Given that the Kymera is clearly based on Harry's wand, it's hardly surprising that they would look alike. I've edited my answer to indicate that it *might* be that. Find me some better evidence and I'll edit further

Comment: @Valorum Other than asking the person who designed this poster, I'm not sure what other evidence you expect?  The Kymera looks absolutely nothing like Harry's wand.  Harry's wand is organic, the handle is irregular, made of bark and entirely asymmetric.

Comment: @J... - I've asked the guy who designed the poster. Just waiting for a reply.

Comment: @Valorum To be honest, if JK Rowling herself told me that was supposed to be Harry's wand I'd tell her she was wrong.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

That is a [sonic screwdriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_screwdriver) from *Dr. Who*.

[image: Sonic screwdriver]

Specifically, I believe that's the [Mark IX model](https://sites.google.com/site/b01a1151104536/) used by the 11th and 12th Doctors.

Comment: I honestly thought it was a lightsaber until I noticed the lightsaber that is ignited in the top right. What is the object on the bottom right? And what do the words say? I can't read them since I am bad with reading cursive and it is in a circle shape which makes it even harder for me.

Comment: Bottom right is the handle portion of Harry Potter's wand. The circle of script is the inscription on the One Ring from Lord of the Rings. It's not in cursive, it is Black Speech written in an Elvish script.

Comment: @DarthVader - You thought it was a lightsaber?

Comment: @camden_kid I thought the same.

Comment: @zabeus That it was a lightsaber or that Darth Vader thought it was a lightsaber? :-)

Comment: @camden_kid What's wrong with my assumption? I haven't watched Doctor Who.

Comment: @DarthVader What's your username?

Comment: @camden_kid can't you see it? It is Darth Vader.

Answer (score 140):

Purely for the sake of completeness, this image is ["The Geeky Hallows" by artist TheHookshot](https://en-gb.facebook.com/thehookshot/posts/782136341869441).

The objects are:

- [Link's "Master Sword](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Master_Sword)" (Zelda BOTW, etc)
- [Gandalf the White's staff](http://www.thehobbitmovieswords.com/gandalf-the-white-staff.html) (LOTR)
- [The inscription from the One Ring](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Ring-inscription) (LOTR)
- [Mark IX Sonic Screwdriver](https://sites.google.com/site/b01a1151104536/) (Doctor Who)
- [Qui-Gon Jinn's Lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn%27s_lightsaber) (Star Wars)
- [Harry Potter's (Broken) Wand](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter%27s_wand) (or possibly a [Kymera Magic Wand Remote control](http://www.thewandcompany.com/kymera-wand/)) (HP)

And the whole thing is based on the [Sign of the Deathly Hallows](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sign_of_the_Deathly_Hallows) from Harry Potter.

[image]

Comment: And the whole thing is the Hallows pattern from HP.

Comment: Weirdly, it's only the handle of Harry's wand.

Comment: @Irishpanda - It got snapped in half

Comment: Gotta be nitpicky - that's Link from Twilight Princess, not Breath of the Wild.

Comment: @Zeus - We do nitpicky in these parts.

Comment: Specifying a single *Legend of Zelda* game seems wrong—the Master Sword has pretty much always looked like that. Even before game systems could depict with that much detail, the illustrations that came with them had it looking like that, at least as far back as *A Link to the Past* (I cannot find good images from *Legend of Zelda* or *Zelda II* so I’m not sure about those).

Comment: I don't buy the bottom right being a broken wand, the object in the image is much to 'machined' to be a broken wooden stick

Comment: (Found the answer; turns out *A Link to the Past* was the game that introduced the Master Sword, and so *Legend of Zelda* and *Zelda II* have no depiction of it.)

Comment: @NKCampbell - The tool tips for the original picture include a tag for "Wand" and "harry Potter". I've looked and Harry's is the only one that matches the image

Comment: Kinda dumb that there's more than one reference to LOTR and HP. Is there really only that much SF&F?

Comment: For a while, it felt like only Harry Potter existed on this SE.  Made me wish we could filter out tags on the stream of questions.

Comment: @RomaH - Are you unaware of the "Ignore Tag" button on the right hand side of your screen?

Comment: @RomaH [You can!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/24927)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Your link goes to your own personal preferences! (Dropping the number works.)

Comment: That is not Harry Potter's wand.  That's the [Kymera Wand](http://www.thewandcompany.com/kymera-wand/) - a remote control for your TV and such.  Harry's wand is made of wood, and looks like a piece of wood.  It is not stylized in any way like that.